# Spring boot mock @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

I have a class that I want to test and it is annotated with `@PropertySource("file:${resources.properties}")`.
In the test class, I have added the annotation `@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:test.properties"})`.
In the test.properties file I have the property `resources.properties=C:/Users/User/Resources.properties`.
I would like to change the value of the resources.properties variable to a path that points to the classpath, so that the execution of the tests does not depend on the machine.
Something like this: `resources.properties=classpath:/Resources.properties`.
But I can't get it to work.
The error thrown is that it cannot find the file
"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [.SomeController]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath:\Resources.properties (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) ".

How can I get it?

The question would be: how can I add a route to the classpath in a variable in the test.properties file?
Why doesn't this work?
resources.properties=classpath:/Resources.properties

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this worked: `resources.properties=src\\test\\resources\\Resources.properties`